# oracle - result list - exchange data at odd index with data at even index

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I'm working on oracle 10g and I have a query that returns a list of data. I need to **change order of result list, one by one**. Here is an example of my need:

**before order change:**

```
id | name
 1 | name1
 2 | name2
 3 | name3
 4 | name4
 5 | name5
```

**after order change:**

```
id | name
 2 | name2
 1 | name3
 4 | name4
 3 | name3
 5 | name5
```

In the other words, **I want to exchange data at odd index with data at even index**. Is there any command for doing this kind of work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, simple way is using analytic function [row_number](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm)

```
  select *
    from (select id, name, row_number() over(order by id) rn
            from (select level id, 'name' || level name
                    from dual
                  connect by level <= 20)
           order by rn)
   order by decode(mod(rn, 2), 0, rn - 2, rn)
```

Comment: Why do you need to order by rn in the subquery?

Comment: Yeah I know, there is no need to be set order, it was just for me. I just forgot to remove order by clause before posting query to here.